# Form data is saving and validation message is also displaying

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

We are using the callbackpanel for the validation of the Devexpress controls but what actually happening is :

If we click submit button without entering any thing in textboxes in the form. It is showing the validation messages but it is also saving the blank data to the database.

I want to know if validation message is showing then why event in backend is calling for saving data ?

Comment: Nobody is going to be able to give you an answer without some code being posted here.

Comment: I'm guessing there are javascript errors that prevent the Validator from triggering correctly. But you should ALWAYS do server side validation also since javascript can easily be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Basically in DevExpress ASPxCallbackPanel, a **Button Click does not trigger a Callback, it triggers a Postback** that is the difference between an UpdatePanel and a CallbackPanel.

So you have to call the **ASPxCallbackPanelClient.PerformCallback('PARAM');** instead.

You did not mention how you trigger the callback, you did not show how your ASPxButton code looks or how your ASPxCallbackPanel looks or how your Validator looks, so considering that please see code below that works very well in you scenario

**All the controls as DX, including validators and buttons**

```
<dx:ASPxCallbackPanel runat="server" ID="cbpDIActions" ClientInstanceName="cbpDIActions" OnCallback="cbpDIActions_Callback">
    <panelcollection>
                    <dx:PanelContent>

<dx:ASPxSpinEdit ID="txtBuilFixtNoBathrooms" runat="server" ValidationSettings-RequiredField-IsRequired="true" ValidationSettings-ValidationGroup="SubmitValidation">

                                    </dx:ASPxSpinEdit>


<dx:ASPxButton ID="btn" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Text="Process" UseSubmitBehavior="False"
                ValidationSettings-ValidationGroup="SubmitValidation" CausesValidation="true"
                >
                <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s,e){
                   ASPxClientEdit.ValidateGroup('SubmitValidation');
                    if (ASPxClientEdit.AreEditorsValid()) {
                        if(!cbpDIActions.InCallback()) { 
                          cbpDIActions.PerformCallback('PARAM');}
                        }                                   
                    }" />
            </dx:ASPxButton>

                    </dx:PanelContent>
                </PanelCollection>                
            </dx:ASPxCallbackPanel>
```

And in the backend you put all your code in the callback event

```
protected void cbpDIActions_Callback(object sender, DevExpress.Web.CallbackEventArgsBase e)
    {

        if (e.Parameter != null && e.Parameter.ToString() == "PARAM")
        {
//PROCESS YOUR CODE
}
}
```